# Checking elements insde tuples in a tuple

Tags: for-loop, tuples, maze

So basically im freaking out about this because, i want to check in all the tuples inside the major tuple if there is any negative numbers and if there is i want the function to return False and if there's not i want it to return True. The thing is that it only checks until the 1st element of the 2nd tuple and i can't figure out what's wrong with the code really. So if anyone could help me i would appreciate it a lot.

```
 maze = ((1,3),(4,-1))

def lab2(maze):
    for i in range(len(maze)):
       for y in maze[i+1]:
           if maze[i][y] < 0:
               return False
           else:
               return True

print(lab2(maze))
```

BTW i forgot to metion that i also want to check if there are duplicated tuples and if there are i want the the function to return false, but its not working

```
maze = ((1,2),(3,4),(3,4))

def eh_conj_posicoes(maze):
    for row in maze:
        for el in row:
            if el < 0:
                return False
    tup = ()
    for row2 in maze:
        tup = tup + maze[0]
        if row2[1:] is tup:
            return False
        else:
            tup = tup + row2
    return True

print(eh_conj_posicoes(maze))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with the code, but the problem that prevents you from going further is that when you return from a function, the function will not proceed. So, if you want to check all the elements in the data structure, and return False if any of them is negative, only return True when you are done checking all the elements. Now, only one element is checked, function returns and does not proceed.

```
def lab2(maze):
    for row in maze:
        for el in row:
            if el < 0: 
                return False

    # Now all for loops have completed 
    # without returning False (i.e. no negative nubmer)
    # So, now we can return True
    return True
```

Comment: Man, ur a genius thanks a lot man. Actually i tried that 1st but it wasnt working (problably because of the return True), but thanks man.

Comment: @MartimCorreia You can send more appreciation by up-voting and accepting my answer.

Comment: btw how do i forgot something how do i check if there is a duplicated tuple and if there is i want the function to return false

Comment: @MartimCorreia Just ask a new question for the other thing. Also, you still haven't accepted my answer...

Comment: Click the check mark next to the answer. You can also up-vote with the arrows. About the other question. Checkout sets, but also, just learn some basic programming, you just seems to be doing stuff without really knowing what you are doing.